# SQL Report Returning Nulls

Tags: sql, null, where-clause

I have written a report and im having a little bother with NULL values.

In my report i had a WHERE clause:

```
WHERE Cust.Ref LIKE ?
```

This clause caused issues with another section of my report (Nominal Codes).  When i filtered on a nominal code, it returned 0 results where it should have returned 34 results.

I removed the WHERE clause and it worked fine...Great i have found the issue.

I changed my WHERE clause to:

```
WHERE (Cust.Ref LIKE ? OR Cust.Ref IS NULL)
```

This fixed the nomincal code issue but now when i filter by a customer reference it also brings back all NULL values.

Can someone please advise?

Thanks.

Comment: try COALESCE(filed, defaultvalue) ='defaultvalue') - will convert null to default value

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the where clause around a bit to check for a null placeholder value.

```
WHERE (? IS NULL OR Cust.Ref LIKE ?)
```